Understanding Fluentd Splunk Forwarding Configs
I have set up Fluentd daemonsets to send logs to Splunk from AWS EKS clusters. Logs are being forwarded to HEC endpoint. I however see multiple events appear in a single output line on Splunk currently. There are few that do appear properly formatted as json but majority of the search result has multiple events clubbed together.
This is how it looks:
{"**host**": "1.2.3.4","time": 1234.56,"index": "index-name","source": "/var/log/containers/loremipsum.log","sourcetype": "kube:container:abc","fields": {"pod": "pod-name","container_name": "container-name","cluster_name": "cluster-name","env": "dev"},"event": "\u001b[2m2024-05-08T20:52:10.007968Z\u001b[0m \u001b[32m INFO\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32magent::apiclient\u001b[0m\u001b[32m: \u001b[32mAPI Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...\u001b[0m"}{"**host**": "1.2.3.4","time": 1234.56,"index": "index-name","source": "/var/log/containers/loremipsum.log","sourcetype": "kube:container:abc","fields": {"pod": "pod-name","container_name": "container-name","cluster_name": "cluster-name","env": "dev"},"event": "\u001b[2m2024-05-08T20:52:10.007968Z\u001b[0m \u001b[32m INFO\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32magent::apiclient\u001b[0m\u001b[32m: \u001b[32mAPI Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...\u001b[0m"}

It appears a single stack trace line is being split into multiple events.
{"host":"1.2.3.4","time":"1715227910.7105658","index":"index-name","source":"source-a.log","sourcetype":"kubernetes","fields":{"f_p":"pod-a","pod":"pod-name","namespace":"ns","container_name":"process-agent","container_id":"123ab","cluster_name":"cluster-name","env":"dev"},"event":{"time":"2024-05-09T04:11:50.710565799Z ","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"*2024-05-09 04:11:50 UTC | PROCESS | INFO | (pkg/process/runner/runner.go:233 in logCheckDuration) | Finish pod check #2680 in 10.617119ms*"}} 
{"host":"1.2.3.4","time":"1715227910.727527", "index":"index-name","source":"source-a.log","sourcetype":"kubernetes","fields":{"f_p":"pod-a","pod":"pod-name","namespace":"ns","container_name":"process-agent","container_id":"123ab","cluster_name":"cluster-name","env":"dev"},"event":{"time":"2024-05-09T04:11:50.727526857Z ","stream":"stdout","logtag":"F","log":"2*024-05-09 04:11:50 UTC | PROCESS | INFO | (pkg/process/runner/runner.go:233 in logCheckDuration) | Finish container check #2680 in 26.48722ms*"}}

How can i keep a single stack trace under an event?
